# Bitcoin core closes inbound connections every 10 minutes

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client, connection

I noticed that Bitcoin core will close incoming connections every 10 minutes. Wireshark captures [FIN, ACK] are received from the node. It looks like Bitcoin core is monitoring the connection time. Nodes are disconnected when their individual connection time is 10 minutes. The maximum number of connections is 256.

Bitcoin core source code is too difficult for me to understand. I can't find a reason and conditions when and why Bitcoin core behaves like this.

Can someone explain this "10 minutes behaviour"?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, or platform incompatibility. You may want to report this on https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues.

Comment: It might be worth checking if `maxuploadtarget` is enabled. There is a hard "600 second" period in computing whether nodes should receive any historical data: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/070eaf7fe5920f1fd1dc68e5afa352411d958bb4/src/net.cpp#L2735. This leads to a reverse phenomenon from what you describe (nodes can get no data for exactly 10 minutes and then some data), but it might be worth looking into. `bitcoin-cli getnettottals` will show you the current status.